# Batch command to find highest number in set of strings?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, highest

For instance:

file.txt contains:

```
4.3 - random1
5.6 - random2
2.2 - random3
3 - random4
1.8 - random5
```

I need a command that will output the highest number only, not the preceding text.

Ie.

```
Output = 5.6
```

Comment: This is not a coding service! Please provide code, you have already and ask a specific question!

Comment: My previous question was answered by a generous person giving me a batch file to achieve the task I needed. Is it just the case that you don't believe he should have been so generous...? Sorry if I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: I do not only think so, it is not on-topic here, however I sometimes do this as well, but usually you should approach the problem yourself and then ask when you have a certain problem.

Comment: Ok. I apologise. New here. I'll try some more ideas first and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [SORTN.bat](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.SortTextWithNumbers) a try.

Here is the code for it as well.

```
@ECHO OFF
if "%~1"=="/?" (
    echo.Sorts text by handling first number in line as number not text
    echo.
    echo.%~n0 [n]
    echo.
    echo.  n     Specifies the character number, n, to
    echo.        begin each comparison.  3 indicates that
    echo.        each comparison should begin at the 3rd
    echo.        character in each line.  Lines with fewer
    echo.        than n characters collate before other lines.
    echo.        By default comparisons start at the first
    echo.        character in each line.
    echo.
    echo.Description:
    echo.        'abc10def3' is bigger than 'abc9def4' because
    echo.        first number in first string is 10
    echo.        first number in second string is 9
    echo.        whereas normal text compare returns 
    echo.        'abc10def3' smaller than 'abc9def4'
    echo.
    echo.Example:
    echo.        To sort a directory pipe the output of the dir
    echo.        command into %~n0 like this:
    echo.           dir /b^|%~n0
    echo.
    echo.Source: http://www.dostips.com
    goto:EOF
)
if "%~1" NEQ "~" (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in ('"%~f0 ~ %*|sort"') do echo.%%b
    goto:EOF
)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a n=%~2+0
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"find /n /v """') do (
    set f=,%%B
    (
        set f0=!f:~0,%n%!
        set f0=!f0:~1!
        rem call call set f=,%%%%f:*%%f0%%=%%%%    
        set f=,!f:~%n%!
    )
    for /f "delims=1234567890" %%b in ("!f!") do (
        set f1=%%b
        set f1=!f1:~1!
        call set f=0%%f:*%%b=%%
    )
    for /f "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWWXYZ~`@#$*_-+=:;',.?/\ " %%b in ("!f!") do (
        set f2=00000000000000000000%%b
        set f2=!f2:~-20!
        call set f=%%f:*%%b=%%
    )
    echo.!f1!!f2!!f!,%%B
    rem echo.-!f0!*!f1!*!f2!*!f!*%%a>&2
)
```

I gave it a try using this input as an example

```
4.3 - random1
11.3 - random6
5.6 - random2
2.2 - random3
100.1 - random8
3 - random4
1.8 - random5
11.12 - random7
11.11 - random7
```

This is how I ran it but you should be able to capture the output as well using a `FOR /F` command just like Stephan showed you in his answer.

```
type sortme.txt |sortn.bat
```

Output

```
1.8 - random5
2.2 - random3
3 - random4
4.3 - random1
5.6 - random2
11.11 - random7
11.12 - random7
11.3 - random6
100.1 - random8
```

Comment: You could also give Dave Benham's JSORT a try. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595

Comment: @Billy pick an answer.

Comment: @Squashman I like your script. I have a list very similar to your example like `10.23 "c:\path\to\dir"`, would you mind telling me how to pick the directory (without number) of the last line (with the highest number) into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

`sort` will sort in correct order (Attention: this is sorting strings, not numbers, but will work fine for your example. Note that with string comparison `5` or `6.3` are "bigger" than `15`).

Put a `for` around to process the ouput (Standard tokens is 1 and Space is a standard delimiter, so the `for /f` gets only the first element - your desired number)

```
for /f %%a in ('sort t.txt') do set high=%%a
echo %high%
```

**EDIT** to also process numbers higher than 10. Note: there is no math involved - it's just clever string manipulation.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=. " %%a in (t.txt) do (
    set a=0000%%a
    if "%%b"=="-" (echo !a:~-4!) else (echo !a:~-4!.%%b)
  )
)>temp.txt
type temp.txt
pause
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=0" %%a in ('sort temp.txt') do set high=%%a

echo %high%
```

Comment: Might want to clarify to the user what the special case is.  What happens when 11 or 21 are added to the list.

Comment: @Squashman: yeah - better to tell the obvious (at least to some of us `;)`). Done.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be able to recognise decimal numbers. So it needs to be able to grab the real highest number even when any number is entered. Thanks though I appreciate the help!

Comment: Note that batch can only handle integers. You either have to implement fractions by a lot of code or use another language.

Answer (score 0):

The following script does proper sorting of fractional numbers with eight digits before and after the decimal separator `.` at most:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"  & rem // (input file; `%~1` means first command line argument)
set /A "_ZPAD=8" & rem // (number of zeroes to be used for temporary padding)

set "_ZERO=" & for /L %%K in (0,1,%_ZPAD%) do set "_ZERO=!_ZERO!0"

for /F "usebackq delims=- " %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%I in ("%%L.") do (
        set "INT=%_ZERO%%%I" & set "FRA=%%J%_ZERO%"
        set "$NUM_!INT:~-%_ZPAD%!_!FRA:~,%_ZPAD%!=%%L"
    )
)
set "MIN=" & set "MAX="
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%L in ('2^> nul set $NUM') do (
    if not defined MIN set "MIN=%%L"
    set "MAX=%%L"
)
echo Minimum: %MIN%
echo Maximum: %MAX%

endlocal
exit /B
```